# Utility for syntax validation

Tags: python, syntax, pyparsing

I have very unique situation where the syntax needs to be validated only for the AND,OR,NOT without any value assignment using any programming language.Any direct utilities would be great.Any suggesstions are appreciated.

Example
q or not (p and r) -Valid
q not or p or q    -Not Valid

My starting point is this any suggestions on top this.It parses but I am trying to figure out a way to find valid vs not valid.

```
import pyparsing as pp

operator = pp.Regex("AND|OR|NOT").setName("operator")
number = pp.Regex(r"[+-]?\d+(:?\.\d*)?(:?[eE][+-]?\d+)?")
identifier = pp.Word(pp.alphas, pp.alphanums + "_")
comparison_term = identifier | number 
condition = pp.Group(comparison_term + operator + comparison_term)

expr = pp.operatorPrecedence(condition,[
                            ("NOT", 1, pp.opAssoc.RIGHT, ),
                            ("AND", 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, ),
                            ("OR", 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, ),
                            ])

#x=expr.parseString("P AND Q OR X AND Y")
x=expr.parseString("P AND Q NOT X AND Y")

print(x)
```

Comment: I haven't read the documentation, but I find it hard to believe that it doesn't report an error some way if the input doesn't match the grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to define operator here as:

```
operator = pp.oneOf("< > = <= >= !=").setName("operator")
```

and to get your parser to match your input strings, `condition` must also accept just plain identifiers:

```
condition = pp.Group(comparison_term + operator + comparison_term) | identifier
```

Now you can run your parser using `expr.runTests`:

```
expr.runTests("""\
    P AND Q NOT X AND Y
    P AND Q AND NOT X AND Y
    P AND Q > 1000 OR NOT Z
    """, fullDump=False)
```

prints:

```
P AND Q NOT X AND Y
        ^
FAIL: Expected end of text, found 'N'  (at char 8), (line:1, col:9)

P AND Q AND NOT X AND Y
[['P', 'AND', 'Q', 'AND', ['NOT', 'X'], 'AND', 'Y']]

P AND Q > 1000 OR NOT Z
[[['P', 'AND', ['Q', '>', '1000']], 'OR', ['NOT', 'Z']]
```

EDIT: To capture parsing errors, you would not use runTests (though runTests is good for parser testing). Instead you would call `parseString` inside a Python try-except block, and capture ParseExceptions:

```
try:
    results = expr.parseString(user_input)
except ParseException as pe:
    print("error at", pe.loc)
```

ParseExceptions have helpful attributes like `lineno`, `col`, `loc` and `line`. You can read more about how to use them here https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/pyparsing_2.4.6/pyparsing.html?highlight=ParseException#pyparsing.ParseException .

Comment: Thanks PaulMcG.Appreciate your help. Once i introduce the brances ( )  it does not throw the error it simple breaks and how to capture these error to throw back to the users?

Comment: result=expr.runTests("P AND Q NOT (X AND Y)",fullDump=False) .I was able to figure out the results capturing.But not the braces yet.

Comment: infixNotation includes handling of ()'s to override the defined precedence of operations, so you shouldn't have to do anything in addition to what is already there. More info on infixNotation here: https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/pyparsing_2.4.6/pyparsing.html?highlight=infixNotation#pyparsing.infixNotation